# Closing an application (fast)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

I am creating a loop which needs to open and close fiels often. Furthermore this needs to be done quickly.  I have used pywinauto to do this, yet it does not seem to work consistant enough.

```
import pywinauto
from time import sleep
import ctypes
import os

os.startfile(file_path)

# a bunch of keyboard events, which opens a seccond  window 

ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x12, 0, 0, 0) #Alt
ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x73, 0, 0, 0) #F4
ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x73, 0, 0x0002, 0) #F4
ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x12, 0, 0x0002, 0) #Alt
sleep(0.2)
```

Now my seccond window is closed, I still need to close the first window. I can not do this with keyboard strokes, since the window is not selected. currenly I use this to close the window:

```
app = pywinauto.application.Application(backend="uia") 
app.connect(path="myapplication.exe")
app.kill()
```

This method often works. However, when I loop the code a large number of times, finding and connecting the window can sometimes fail.
I am looking for a reliable method to close the file, and I would also like it to be fast.

Comment: Which pywinauto version do you use? And can you provide the traceback of a typical failure?

Comment: Also why not use `from pywinauto.keyboard import SendKeys; SendKeys('^{F4}')` and `app.FirstWindowName.set_focus()`

Comment: I do not know how to check which version I have.

Comment: `print(pywinauto.__version__)`

Answer (score 2):

This solution seems to suit me well.

```
os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM Myapplication.exe")
```

Comment: This is a bad solution if there are other instances of the app running on the system. It will kill them all.

Comment: In my specific case this was not an issue, although I must admit it is far from ideal/clean coding